# Steam (Mac) game location

Tags: steam, macos

A few months ago, I restored my Mac from a Time Machine backup. Now, when I try to play a game on Steam (Civ 5 for example), Steam does not seem to be aware of the location of the game. I found the game on my hard drive, located at:

`~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/sid meier's civilization v`

I believe the game was previously referenced in `~/Applications/`

If I open the `Civilization V.app` for the game, it bounces in the dock and disappears when I click it.

Is there a way to restore Steam's memory of the location of the game?

Comment: Awesome question, but do you have this issue with other games? If not, you can hone the question a tad to deal only with Civ V.

Comment: I can't recall if I did. I ended up downloading again from Steam.

Answer (score 11):

How to find your games and files on Mac is:

1. Click on desktop.
2. Click on Go which is the 5th button in on your left.
3. Go the the 2nd last command which is Go To Folder...
4. Click on it and enter this text ~/Library/Application Support
5. Find the Steam Folder and click on it.
6. Go into the steamapps folder
7. Go into Common Apps.
8. Redownload it.
9. Search Steam for any bugs or wrong algorithms they may find.
10. There you go it should have worked!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I don't have a steam folder there on macOS Catalina

Answer (score 9):

Steam normally stores its games in:

`/Users/<your user name>/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/`

You might have luck moving your game folders here, or pointing Steam itself to the game folder, but really your best bet would probably be to re-download the games again in Steam :-/

Answer (score 2):

**Aspyr** - company who port this game on Mac - make special folder in documents for part of app data. Lack of this data makes this problem AFAIK.

```
/Users/YourUser/Documents/Aspyr/Sid Meier's Civilization 5
```

Restore this folder and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

go to /Users/(your name)/Library/Application Support
then find steam delete the folder then open steam login and it will redownload your stuff