# Where is the Steam game savefile location on OSX?

Tags: steam, macos

Specifically asking about Mac OSX Sierra.

(Not the game application location.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steam (Mac) game location](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/78919/145980)

Comment: @MageXy Save location (this question) and game executable location (that question) aren't the same thing (except for *some* games that put their saves beside their executables). The problem here is that games all put their saves in different places and we don't know what game is being asked about, so we can't say where the save files are. Then again, maybe this question *is* asking where the executables are “saved” and isn't asking about *save files*, and I'm just confused by that. (Either way, I've voted “unclear”.)

Comment: Arda, please tell us which game's save files you're looking for? Steam doesn't control where games put their save files, so where to find the save files depends on which game you're asking about.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes here. This is not too broad, nor is it unclear. Furthermore, the linked 'duplicate' does seem to ask the same thing, but none of the answers are accepted for that question.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf It's ambiguous. They might be asking about game executable location, or a game's savefile location. If it's the former it's a dup (hence those votes), if it's the latter it's a new question. Either way it's currently unclear (hence *those* votes).

Comment: Now that it's clear that the question is asking about the location of the save files, I have a clear answer for this if we want to re-open.

Answer (score 4):

Save game storage location varies by game. The most common locations are `~/Library/Application Support/` and `~/Documents/`. If it's not in either of those locations, your best bet will be to look on PC Gaming Wiki for the particular game you're concerned with: http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Category:OS_X